# How many closed paths with the operations $+1$, $-1$, and $\times 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, asymptotics, markov-chains

Consider a finite sequence of $n$ integers denoted $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ where $x_1=x_n=0$ and $x_{n+1}$ is either equal to $x_n+1$, $x_n-1$ or $2x_n$. Is there a good way to count how many such sequences there are, with either an exact or asymptotic formula?

Phrased differently, if you start with the number $0$ and are allowed to add one to your number, subtract one from your number, or double your number $n$ times, how many ways can you end up back at $0$? Is there a good approximate/asymptotic formula for this in terms of $n$?

I have no idea how to start solving this. It would be nice to find some sort of generating function, but I’m not sure how to set one up.

Comment: The original problem is not asking to return to 0, which makes it a trivial problem. Then "phrased differently one" does.

Comment: @N.S. Whoops! Thanks for catching that. I’ve fixed my problem description.

Comment: The first terms of the sequence are 1,3,5,15,29,83,177 but nothing appears in https://oeis.org/

Answer (score 6):

It has (kinda) exponential growth.

Let $f_n$ be the number of solutions. Then, it is easy to see that 
$$f_{m+n-1}\geq f_n\cdot f_m$$

Indeed, if $x_1,.., x_n$ is a solution for $n$ and $y_1,.., y_m$ is a solution for $m$ then 
$$x_1,...,x_n,y_2,.., y_m$$
is a solution for $m+n-1$.

From here, you get that 
$$f_{n+2}\geq f_3 f_n= 3f_n$$

Hence, 
$$f_{2n}\geq 3^{n-1} f_2 =\frac{1}{3} \cdot (\sqrt{3})^{2n} \\
f_{2n+1}\geq 3^n f_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot (\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}$$

Also note that at each step there are at most 3 choices, therefore
$$f_n \leq 3^{n-1}$$

From here, it follows that 
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot (\sqrt{3})^{n} \leq f_n \leq \frac{1}{3} \cdot 3^n$$

**Extra** Same way, for each fixed $k$ we have 
$$f_{n+k-1} \geq f_n \cdot f_k$$
giving 
$$f_n \geq C (\sqrt[k-1]{f_k})^n$$

Note that 
$$\sqrt[6]{83}~2.088
\sqrt[7]{177}~2.095$$

**Added** Note that the equation 
$$f_{m+n-1}\geq f_n\cdot f_m$$
implies that 
$$g(m+n) \leq g(m)+g(n)$$
where $g(n)=- \ln(f(n+1))$.

Then, by [Fekete's Subadditive Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Sequences) the limit

$$l= \lim_n \frac{g(n)}{n}$$
exists and $l=\inf\frac{g(n)}{n}$.

Note that this gives that 
$$\lim_n \frac{\ln(f(n+1))}{n}=-l \\
\lim_n  \ln(f(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}})=-l \\
\lim_n f(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{-l}\\
\lim_n\sqrt[n]{ \frac{f(n+1)}{e^{-l}} }=1$$
meaning that the $b$ in your formula must be $e^-l$.

This show that asymptotically, in some sense, $f_n \simeq e^{-l}$. But it is  not clear if you can get some $a$ so that, in a stronger sense $f_n\simeq ae^{-l}$.

As for finding the $l$, Fekete's Subadditive Lemma tells you exatly what it is, but I would be surprised if we can calculate it explicitely.

Note that 
$$l=\inf\frac{g(n)}{n} \Rightarrow l=\inf \frac{- \ln(f(n+1))}{n} \Rightarrow -l=\sup \ln(f(n+1)^\frac{1}{n}) \Rightarrow e^{-l}=\sup \sqrt[n]{f(n+1)}$$

Comment: Do you think there is any good way of finding constants $a,b$ so that $f_n\sim a\cdot b^n$?

Comment: @Frpzzd see the edit.

Comment: Are you sure about $\sqrt{5}$? Considering two steps only, I find only 3 possibilities, hence a factor $\sqrt{3}$, which is by the way less than $2$, and the latter is easily seen to be a lower bound for the exponential growth (by comparison with simple random walk say).

Comment: @Olivier ty... As the comparison with random walks, you need to count the number of random walks returning to the origin.

Comment: Yes : this adds up a $1/\sqrt{N}$ factor (mid-binomial coefficient) that does not perturb the exponential scale you look at...

Comment: Anyway, consider the first elements of the sequence $f_{n+1}$ as enumerated by Robert Z, take them to the power $1/n$ (beware of mix-up in the indices...): one of them should bypass $2$ (I guess), and then you're in business to show that the exponent is greater than $2$.

Comment: @Olivier $83>64$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can set a function and try to find a formula. Though I **haven't finished**, I hope it will inspire you guys.

Let a function $f_{n} \left(x\right)$ mean that the number of ways to take $n$ steps from $x$ to $0$, which each step can only be $\boxed{+1}$, $\boxed{-1}$ and $\boxed{\times2}$ from the previous term. then, we get the following definition:

$1)$ $f_{n} \left(x\right)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when }n=0,x=0\\ 0 & \text{when }n=0,x\ne0\\ 0 & \text{when }n<0\end{cases}$

$2)$ $f_{n} \left(x\right)=f_{n} \left(-x\right)$

$3)$ $f_{n+1} \left(x\right)=f_{n} \left(x+1\right)+f_{n} \left(x-1\right)+f_{n} \left(2x\right)$

$4)$ Our answer is $f_n \left(0\right)$

Then, we try to generate a function $P_n \left(x\right)= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_n \left(k\right) x^k$. However, here's come the question:

$\quad P_{n+1} \left(x\right)\\=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n+1} \left(k\right) x^k\\ =\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left[f_{n} \left(k+1\right)+f_{n} \left(k-1\right)+f_{n} \left(2k\right)\right]x^k \\=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(k-1\right) x^k+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(k+1\right) x^k+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(2k\right) x^k \\=x\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(k-1\right) x^{k-1}+\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(k+1\right) x^{k+1}+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(2k\right) x^k \\= \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)P_n \left(x\right)+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{n} \left(2k\right) x^k$

I can't find a way to express  $f_{n} \left(2k\right)$ by $f_{n} \left(k\right)$, so I can't finish it. So, if you guys have some advices, please tell me in the comment immediately. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it will help or not, but $f_n(x) = 0$ if $n < x$.

Comment: Also $f(n, n-k)$ is a polynomial of degree $\lfloor k/2 \rfloor$ for $n \ge 2k-1$. For example, $f(n, n-5) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 3n+18$ for $n \ge 9$

Answer (score 1):

If we restrict ourselves to sequences which stay between $A$ and $B$, we can get an exact count, and thus a lower bound for the original problem. Let $M$ be the matrix with rows and columns indexed by $\{A, A+1, \cdots, B-1,B \}$, with $M_{ij}=1$ if $j=i+1$, $i-1$ or $2i+1$, and $M_{ij}=0$ otherwise. Let $\vec{e}$ be the vector whose $0$-entry is $1$ and whose other entries are $0$. Then the number of sequences is $\vec{e}^T M^n \vec{e}$. For $n$ large, this grows like $\lambda^n$ where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $M$.

I computed this largest eigenvalue for $A=-B$ with $5 \leq B \leq 20$ and got the following sequence, which seems to be approaching a limit around 2.3:

```
2.28034, 2.29867, 2.30516, 2.31369, 2.31662, 2.31967, 2.32071, 2.32196,
2.32238, 2.32282, 2.32296, 2.32313, 2.32319, 2.32325, 2.32327, 2.32329
```

The characteristic polynomial doesn't seem enlightening: For $(A,B) = (-10,10)$, I get

```
   (-1 + t) * (1 + t) * (1 - 3 t - t^2 + t^3) * (1 + 3 t - 3 t^2 - 4 t^3 + t^4 + t^5) *
   (-1 - 13 t - 6 t^2 + 53 t^3 + 21 t^4 - 76 t^5 - 21 t^6 + 44 t^7 + 8 t^8 - 11 t^9 - t^10 + t^11)
```

The largest root, 2.31967, is a root of the degree 11 factor.

Comment: I checked up to $f(773)$ and it seems like $\sqrt[n]{f(n)}$ is closer to $2.5$, as $\sqrt[773]{f(773)} \approx 2.504$.